# phpqrcode how to implement

Tags: php, qr-code

I am trying to update my codes by saving the data with QR Code.
I tried to implement [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rverBQL8A3g) tutorial, but It is not saving the QR Code, after I submit the form the page just keeps loading, it only saves the data from the form without the QR Code.

Any help?

**this is how I added the udate**

```
    include"phpqrcode/qrlib.php";
    $folderTemp = 'assets/img/';
    $c = $a;
    $qrimage = $a.".png";
    $qual = 'H';
    $ukuran = 6;
    $padding = 0;
    QRCode :: png($c,$folderTemp.$qrimage,$qual,$ukuran,$padding);

    function save_register(){
    extract($_POST);
    $data = " event_id = '$event_id' ";
    $data .= ", name = '$name' ";
    $data .= ", address = '$address' ";
    $data .= ", email = '$email' ";
    $data .= ", contact = '$contact' ";
    $data .= ", pacote = '$pacote' ";
    $data .= ", qrimage = '$qrimage' ";
    if(isset($status))
    $data .= ", status = '$status' ";
    if(isset($payment_status))
    $data .= ", payment_status = '$payment_status' ";
    else
    $data .= ", payment_status = '0' ";
    if(empty($id)){
    $save = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO audience set ".$data);
    }else{
    $save = $this->db->query("UPDATE audience set ".$data." where id=".$id);
    }
    if($save)
    return 1;
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a scope issue - `$qrimage` isn't passed into the function so has no value inside there. You need to pass it in as a parameter, then you can use it. Please don't just declare it as global.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Also, be warned that your database queries are widely open for SQL injection - have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked